# React-query avoid trigger query with using mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-query

In a components container I've to manage
two domains, posts and users like:

```
const { data: posts, isError:isErrorPosts, isLoading: isLoadingPosts } = usePosts();
const createPostMutation = useCreatePost();
const handlerSubmitData = (data: PostDataDto) => {
   createPostMutation.mutate(data);
};
const { data: users,  isError:isErrorUsers, isLoading: isLoadingUsers } = useUsers();
const userFollowMutation = useUserFollow();
const userUnFollowMutation = useUserUnFollow();
const handlerUserStatus = (data: UserStatusDto) => {
    if (data.status === UserStatus.FOLLOW) {
      userFollowMutation.mutate(data.user);
    } else {
      userUnFollowMutation.mutate(data.user);
    }
};
```

When I trigger mutation on a user both users and posts
got updated.
Is there a way to have updated only the users domain?

Hooks code https://codeshare.io/ZJA8QQ

Comment: Need more information. How does your custom hooks look like, what have you used as mutation (query) keys?

Comment: Here it is https://codeshare.io/ZJA8QQ

Comment: judging from your code, the user mutations should invalidate the users query, and the posts mutations should invalidate the posts query. I see nothing in the code that indicates that a user mutation should invalidate both the users and the posts. Do you have a runnable example, maybe codesandbox that shows the issue?

Comment: No, I don't have any codesandbox too long to set up :(